# How can I do a list in list

Tags: list, ionic-framework

I try to generate a list in a another list.

Like this:

- Item
- Item 2

  - Item 2 - 1
  - Item 2 - 2
- Item 3

  - Item 3 - 1

And for the moment I've write this:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-scroll>
    <ion-item collection-repeat="service in allServices | filter:searchFilter | orderBy:'Host.name'" item="servIn" class="message">

        HOST

        <p>Services :</p>

        <ion-list>
           <ion-item collection-repeat="serv in service.Host.Services" class="messageService">

           </ion-item>
        </ion-list>


    </ion-item>
   </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

But I've this error message:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>   Controller '$ionicScroll', required by directive 'collectionRepeat',
>   can't be found!

And when I add the $ionicScroll to my controller I've got this message:

> Unknown provider: $ionicScrollProvider <- $ionicScroll <-
>   TabsServicesCtrl

If anyone know how to fix this issue!

Comment: just use three different list that will solve your issue or try using divider http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-dividers

Comment: It will work with hundreds items?

Comment: as you can see in above link use divider